# Parsing data nested in Div class using Beautifulsoup Error

Tags: python, json, parsing, beautifulsoup

Good Evening Stackoverflow Forks,

I'm a noob of Python and trying to learn more about it by going to a grad school.
Recently, I got to know an awesome add-in which is BeauifulSoup.
I tried to parse location data from a realty website which is 'Nestio'.

As far as I understood, I made a coding like below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://nestiolistings.com/listings/?listing_type=10&min_price=2500&max_price=3000').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
address = soup.find_all('span', class_ = 'building-title-content')

print(address)
```

The codes I gto by 'inspection' from the website is

[image]

After runnin the code it only shows 'None'...

The possible reason I could think of for not being able to the result is because

-the information is from href? or it is nested too much?

I also try to get the information from page 1 to page 53.
And I was told that I need to use 'Json'.

```
import requests
count = 0
for i in range(53):
    count+=1
    link = 'https://nestiolistings.com/listings/?listing_type=10&min_price=2500&max_price=3000&pageNumber='+str(count)
    req = requests.get(link)
    for i in req.json()['building-title-content']:
        address = (i['building-title-content'])
        print ('Address:', address)
```

So I tried Json code as well but it doesn't seem like work...

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?
Appreciate in advance.
I have struggled with this issue for a month and still didn't get any clue solve this issue...

Comment: You need to login to access information. So probably you're scraping non-existing data from their login page...

Comment: i already logged in and i could see the information... i just couldn't parse the data to my python..

Comment: Python doesn't know what you're doing in your browser. You need to login with Python. It does not import login cookies from your browsers by it self. Google around for 'python requests login'. There are plenty of tutorials out thre on that. If you don't want to learn how to do this then take a look on the browsercookie package. It imports the cookies from your browsers for you...

Comment: Thank you so much! I will take a look into python rquests login